# How can I make my JavaScript (if it's correct) execute after my countdown?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Basically I have created a web page that features a reaction time game. There are 8 squares in a circular pattern in the center of which is a blue circle that on hover hides the instructions which are present on the right hand side of a the page and a countdown from 3 begins.
I want my JavaScript to make it so a random number between 1-8 is generated which will correspond to a square that will turn green for the user to click.
I have not found anything similar anywhere and I'm not sure whether my JavaScript is correct (my HTML and CSS work as intended) as nothing happens because I don't know where or how to run the function I have created (granted it's correct).

```
         <script>
                var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8) +1;
                // generates a random number between 1-8
                function randomWholeNum () {
                    return Math.random();
                }

                    if (randomNum === 1) {
                        document.getElementById("square1").style.background = rgb(0,200,0);
                        //if generated number is 1, square 1 will change to green
                        }
                    else if (randomNum === 2) {
                        document.getElementById("square2").style.background = rgb(0,200,0);
                        //if generated number is 2, square 2 will change to green
                        }
                    else if (randomNum === 3) {
                        document.getElementById("square3").style.background = rgb(0,200,0);
                        //if generated number is 3, square 3 will change to green
                        }
                    else if (randomNum === 4) {
                        document.getElementById("square4").style.background = rgb(0,200,0);
                        //if generated number is 4, square 4 will change to green
                        }      
                    else if (randomNum === 5) {
                        document.getElementById("square5").style.background = rgb(0,200,0);
                        //if generated number is 5, square 5 will change to green
                        } 
                    else if (randomNum === 6) {
                        document.getElementById("square6").style.background = rgb(0,200,0);
                        //if generated number is 6, square 6 will change to green
                        }
                    else if (randomNum === 7) {
                        document.getElementById("square7").style.background = rgb(0,200,0);
                        //if generated number is 7, square 7 will change to green
                        }
                    else (randomNum === 8); {
                        document.getElementById("square8").style.background = rgb(0,200,0);
                        //if generated number is 8, square 8 will change to green
                        }

            </script>
```

I'll also need to add timings to these so it occurs after the countdown however right now I just want a random square to turn green.
Here's my HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="squares"></div>
    <div id="square1"></div>
    <div id="square2"></div>
    <div id="square3"></div>
    <div id="square4"></div>
    <div id="square5"></div>
    <div id="square6"></div>
    <div id="square7"></div>
    <div id="square8"></div>
    <div class="title">
        <img src="title.png" alt="My title">
    </div>
    <div class="movingstuff">
        <div id="circle"></div>
        <div id="instructions">
                <img src="instructions.png">
        </div>
        <div id="howtoplay">
                <img src="howtoplay.png" alt="Instructions">
        </div>        
        <div id="three">
            <img src="three.png" alt="Three">
        </div>
        <div id="two">
            <img src="two.png" alt="Two">
        </div>
        <div id="one">
            <img src="one.png" alt="One">
        </div>

    </body>
```

And my CSS:

```
body {
background-image: url("mountain2.jpg");
}


#square1 {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
position: absolute;
left: 215px;
top: 215px;
background: rgb(180,0,0);
border: 2px solid black;
border-radius: 5px;
}

#square2 {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
position: absolute;
left: 400px;
top: 150px;
background: rgb(180,0,0);
border: 2px solid black;
border-radius: 5px;
}

#square3 {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
position: absolute;
left: 585px;
top: 215px;
background: rgb(180,0,0);
border: 2px solid black;
border-radius: 5px;
}

#square4 {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
position: absolute;
left: 150px;
top: 400px;
background: rgb(180,0,0);
border: 2px solid black;
border-radius: 5px;
}

#square5 {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
position: absolute;
left: 650px;
top: 400px;
background: rgb(180,0,0);
border: 2px solid black;
border-radius: 5px;
}

#square6 {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
position: absolute;
left: 215px;
top: 585px;
background: rgb(180,0,0);
border: 2px solid black;
border-radius: 5px;
}

#square7 {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
position: absolute;
left: 400px;
top: 650px;
background: rgb(180,0,0);
border: 2px solid black;
border-radius: 5px;
}

#square8 {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
position: absolute;
left: 585px;
top: 585px;
background: rgb(180,0,0);
border: 2px solid black;
border-radius: 5px;
}

.movingstuff #circle {
width: 75px;
height: 75px;
position: fixed;
left: 412.5px;
top: 412.5px;
background: rgb(28,60,219);
-moz-border-radius: 50px;
-webkit-border-radius: 50px;
border-radius: 50px;
border: 2px solid black;
opacity: 0.5;
transition: 0.3s;
}

.movingstuff:hover #circle{
opacity: 1;
}

#circle:hover ~ #instructions{
opacity: 0;
}

#circle:hover ~ #howtoplay{
opacity: 0;
}

#circle:hover ~ #three {
animation: numbers 0.5s linear;
-webkit-animation: numbers 0.5s linear;
-moz-animation: numbers 0.5s linear;
animation-delay: 1s;
}

#circle:hover ~ #two {
animation: numbers 0.5s linear;
-webkit-animation: numbers 0.5s linear;
-moz-animation: numbers 0.5s linear;
animation-delay: 2s;
}

#circle:hover ~ #one {
animation: numbers 0.5s linear;
-webkit-animation: numbers 0.5s linear;
-moz-animation: numbers 0.5s linear;
animation-delay: 3s
}

#three {
left: 1110px;
top: 350px;
position: absolute;
opacity: 0;
}

#two {
left: 1110px;
top: 350px;
position: absolute;
opacity: 0;
}

#one {
left: 1110px;
top: 350px;
position: absolute;
opacity: 0;
}


.title {
left: 890px;
top: 75px;
position: absolute;
}

#howtoplay {
left: 890px;
top: 300px;
position: absolute;
transition: 0.5s;
opacity: 1;
}

#instructions {
left: 920px;
top: 350px;
position: absolute;
transition: 0.5s;
opacity: 1;
}

@keyframes numbers {
0%, 100% {opacity: 0;}
50% {opacity: 1;}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your code corrected and simplified:

```js
var oldNum;

function color() {
  if (oldNum !== undefined) {
    document.getElementById("square"+oldNum).style.background = 'rgb(180,0,0)';
  }
  
  var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8) +1;
  document.getElementById("square"+num).style.background = 'rgb(0,200,0)';
  oldNum = num;
}

setInterval(color, 1000);
color();
```

```css
body {
  background-image: url("mountain2.jpg");
}

[id^="square"] {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  background: rgb(180,0,0);
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#square1 {
left: 215px;
top: 215px;
}

#square2 {
left: 400px;
top: 150px;
}

#square3 {
left: 585px;
top: 215px;
}

#square4 {
left: 150px;
top: 400px;
}

#square5 {
left: 650px;
top: 400px;
}

#square6 {
left: 215px;
top: 585px;
}

#square7 {
left: 400px;
top: 650px;
}


#square8 {
left: 585px;
top: 585px;
}

.movingstuff #circle {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 412.5px;
  top: 412.5px;
  background: rgb(28,60,219);
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.movingstuff:hover #circle{
  opacity: 1;
}

#circle:hover ~ #instructions{
  opacity: 0;
}

#circle:hover ~ #howtoplay{
  opacity: 0;
}

#circle:hover ~ #three {
  animation: numbers 0.5s linear;
  -webkit-animation: numbers 0.5s linear;
  -moz-animation: numbers 0.5s linear;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}

#circle:hover ~ #two {
  animation: numbers 0.5s linear;
  -webkit-animation: numbers 0.5s linear;
  -moz-animation: numbers 0.5s linear;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

#circle:hover ~ #one {
  animation: numbers 0.5s linear;
  -webkit-animation: numbers 0.5s linear;
  -moz-animation: numbers 0.5s linear;
  animation-delay: 3s
}

#three {
  left: 1110px;
  top: 350px;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}

#two {
  left: 1110px;
  top: 350px;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}

#one {
  left: 1110px;
  top: 350px;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}

.title {
  left: 890px;
  top: 75px;
  position: absolute;
}

#howtoplay {
  left: 890px;
  top: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  transition: 0.5s;
  opacity: 1;
}

#instructions {
  left: 920px;
  top: 350px;
  position: absolute;
  transition: 0.5s;
  opacity: 1;
}

@keyframes numbers {
  0%, 100% {opacity: 0;}
  50% {opacity: 1;}
}
```

```html
<div class="squares"></div>
<div id="square1"></div>
<div id="square2"></div>
<div id="square3"></div>
<div id="square4"></div>
<div id="square5"></div>
<div id="square6"></div>
<div id="square7"></div>
<div id="square8"></div>
<div class="title">
    <img src="title.png" alt="My title">
</div>
<div class="movingstuff">
  <div id="circle"></div>
  <div id="instructions">
    <img src="instructions.png">
  </div>
  <div id="howtoplay">
    <img src="howtoplay.png" alt="Instructions">
  </div>        
  <div id="three">
    <img src="three.png" alt="Three">
  </div>
  <div id="two">
    <img src="two.png" alt="Two">
  </div>
  <div id="one">
    <img src="one.png" alt="One">
  </div>
</div>
```

1. As others have stated I reduced the JS code to remove the multiple `if` statements.
2. I reduced the repetitive CSS by using an attribute selector.
3. I cleaned up your HTML. You were missing a closing `<div>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the if's are unneccessary, just append `randomNum` to your string. Also I used "backgroundColor" instead of background.

Do not forget! Your setting css and not Javascript! rgb() would call a javascript function. To pass rgb colors to css you have to pass a string.

```
document.getElementById("square"+randomNum).style.backgroundColor = "rgb(0,200,0)";
```

I tried to reconstruct what you want to achieve on this codepen.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rZvKWz

JS Code:

```
window.onload = function(){
  var randomNum = 1;
  setInterval(function(){
         document.getElementById("square"+randomNum).style.backgroundColor = "rgb(180,0,0)";
    randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8) +1;
      document.getElementById("square"+randomNum).style.backgroundColor = "rgb(0,200,0)";
  },3000);
}
```

Comment: Okay, so get rid of all the 'if' statements and replace them with `document.getElementById("square"+randomNum).style.backgroundColor = "rgb(0,200,0)";`

Comment: I added a codepen which, I think, does what you want. @RomanJozaf

Comment: What is the function you created called? As I think I'll just use button onclick and add a timeout to run it (apologies for being so clueless) @filip

Comment: In the codepen you wrote, so I can execute the code using `<button onclick="function name()"></button>` @filip

Comment: I updated the codepen. The function has a name now. @RomanJozaf

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your problem is with JavaScript and not with HTML and CSS and your function is correct (as you said). **you'll need to trigger your function after your countdown by 3 seconds ends**.

So, a good way to do this is using `window.setTimeout()`.

According to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout), you can pass two parameters: the first one is a `callback function` to be executed after the time that you'll set in the next parameter, and the second one is some time in milliseconds.

An example would be: 
`window.setTimeout(() => alert("let's do something after 3 seconds!"), 3000);`

Hope it helps someway.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to execute some function delayed in time you can use `setTimeout` function.